# Кастомный ListView с ImageView

Tags: android, listview

Имеется сильно измененный кастомный ListView. Не могу понять, как к каждому значению в списке прикрутить ImageView. Видел подобные вопросы но так и не понял логики реализации

```
public class SettingFree extends ListActivity  {

    public final static String[] countries = new String[] {
            "раз",
            "два",
            "три",
            "четыре",
            "пять",
            "шесть",
            "семь",
            "восемь",
            "девять",
            "десять",
            "одиннадцать",
            "двенадцать",
            "тринадцать",

    };
    int[] mImageIds  ={ R.drawable.social_studies, R.drawable.history,
            R.drawable.chemistry, R.drawable.computer_science, R.drawable.literature,
            R.drawable.foreign_language, R.drawable.foreign_language, R.drawable.maths,
            R.drawable.russian_language, R.drawable.biology, R.drawable.geography,
            R.drawable.physics};



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.setting_free);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, countries);


        getListView().setAdapter(adapter);


        View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) v;
                chk.setChecked(true);
                int itemCount = getListView().getCount();
                for(int i=0 ; i < itemCount ; i++){
                    getListView().setItemChecked(i, chk.isChecked());
                }
            }
        };


        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkAll);

                int checkedItemCount = getCheckedItemCount();

                if(getListView().getCount()==checkedItemCount)
                    chk.setChecked(true);

                else
                    chk.setChecked(false);
            }

        };


        CheckBox chkAll =  ( CheckBox ) findViewById(R.id.chkAll);


        chkAll.setOnClickListener(clickListener);


        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);


    }


    public int getCheckedItemCount(){

        int cnt = 0;
        SparseBooleanArray positions = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
        final int itemCount = getListView().getCount();

        for(int i=0;i<itemCount;i++){
            if(positions.get(i))
                cnt++;
        }
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.end_setting);
        final int finalCnt1 = cnt;
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ArrayList<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();
                SparseBooleanArray positions = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
                for (int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i++)
                    if (positions.valueAt(i)) ids.add(positions.keyAt(i));

                if (ids.size() > 0) PreferenceManagerApp.saveString(SettingFree.this, "ids", new Gson().toJson(ids));

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(SettingFree.this, MainActivity.class);
                PreferenceManagerApp.setNumber(SettingFree.this, finalCnt1);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        return cnt;



    }




}
```

Адаптер

```
public class SamplePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();

    public SamplePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(PreferenceManagerApp.loadString(context, "ids")))
            ids = new Gson().fromJson(PreferenceManagerApp.loadString(context, "ids"), new TypeToken<ArrayList<Integer>>(){}.getType());

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return SettingFree.countries[ids.get(position)];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (ids.get(position)) {
            case 0:
                return Tab1.newInstance();
            case 1:
                return Tab2.newInstance();
            case 2:
                return Tab3.newInstance();
            case 3:
                return Tab4.newInstance();
            case 4:
                return Tab5.newInstance();
            case 5:
                return Tab6.newInstance();
            case 6:
                return Tab13.newInstance();
            case 7:
                return Tab7.newInstance();
            case 8:
                return Tab8.newInstance();
            case 9:
                return Tab9.newInstance();
            case 10:
                return Tab10.newInstance();
            case 11:
                return Tab11.newInstance();
            case 12:
                return Tab12.newInstance();


        }
        return null;
    }





    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ids.size();
    }
}
```

Только учусь, сильно не пинайте

Comment: Вот тут хороший пример https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/113-urok-54-kastomizatsija-spiska-sozdaem-svoj-adapter.html

Comment: @AlexanderChernin проблема в том, что к каждому элементу списка должна быть присвоена своя картинка. Я находил подобные примеры, но не могу понять, как это все реализовать с минимальными изменениями адаптера. Код адаптера добавил в вопрос

Comment: Изучайте сразу `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Для начала имеет смысл хранить не два списка, а список объектов с двумя полями, например Pair<String, Int> в простейшем случае